# Why abstract classes necessary?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an abstract class ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912475/what-is-an-abstract-class)

1.What is the point of creating a class that can't be instantiated?

Most commonly to serve as a base-class or interface (some languages have a separate interface     construct, some don't) - it doesn't know the implementation (that is to be provided by the subclasses / implementing classes)

2.Why would anybody want such a class?

```
For abstraction and re-use
```

3.What is the situation in which abstract classes become NECESSARY?can anyone brief it with an example?

Comment: It's an exact dupe of a dupe.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't that abstract class are always *necessary*, but they're often quite *convenient*. Suppose I want to write a parser for a particular kind of text file.

```
// hasty code, might be written poorly
public abstract class FileParser<T> {
    private readonly List<T> _contents;
    public IEnumerable<T> Contents {
        get { return _contents.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    protected FileParser() {
        _contents = new List<T>();
    }

    public void ReadFile(string path) {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
            return;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path)) {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
                T value;
                if (TryParseLine(reader.ReadLine(), out value))
                    _contents.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract bool TryParseLine(string text, out T value);
}
```

After throwing together something like the above, I've finished with the boilerplate code any `FileParser`-esque class would need. All I'd need to do for any derived class is simply override the one abstract method--`TryParseLine`--rather than write all the same tedious stuff dealing with streams, etc. Moreover, I could easily add functionality later--such as exception handling--and it will apply to all derived classes.

Answer (score 5):

Abstract classes allow you to write a common piece of code that will defer specific decisions to derived classes, thus reducing code duplication.

Comment: @Otávio Décio:Necessary when the base-class can provide no meaningful default-implementation for a method??

Comment: @bala3569: An abstract base class *can* provide a meaningful default implementation for a method (or for most of it). See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You (may) need abstract classes when you create an inheritance tree, with a single ancestor that cannot be instantiated, simply because it is unknown how some methods could be implemented.

Marking a class as abstract is telling the compiler about:

- ***Example 1*** 
  If you need a single ancestor for a `Car` and a `Bicycle`, you would probably create a `Vehicle` class. You cannot initiate this `Vehicle` class, because it is uncompleted. A `Vehicle` itself will not work. That's why `Vehicle` will be abstract.
- ***Example 2*** 
  Another example from the .Net framework. The `Stream` class is an abstract class that provides basic I/O functionality. It provides a Read and Write method to handle bytes to the underlaying stream.

This stream can be a `FileStream`, `NetworkStream`, `MemoryStream`, and so on. The `Stream` itself does not know how to read or write from the concrete implementation of the stream. But some methods of `Stream` are implemented, because they are shared by all instances of the stream.

This is not possible to do with an interface. So you need to create a class. Since the `Read` and `Write` methods cannot be implemented, `Stream` is marked as abstract. This will prevent the `Stream` class from being created as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes are never strictly necessary. You can always use a non-abstract class and provide stubs for methods that would  otherwise be abstract. You can also approximate aspects of abstract by giving a class only protected constructors.

But non of this is the point. When a class is used to model the generalized properties and behaviour of a group of subclasses, you want to mark it abstract to make your **intentions** clear.

Answer (score 2):

I know I need to save information in between times my application is executed.

I know roughly what methods I'll need to accomplish this.  I also can provide several methods which perform various parts of the overall data storage operation.

I know my customers have different requirements for data storage, based on preferences (MS Sql, Oracle) and laws (health industry security requirements).

How can I provide an object that does 80% of the heavy lifting, but leaves the last 20% open for customization?

An abstract base class allows us to customize that last 20% for each customer yet reuse the 80% of common code in the base class.  Also, abstract classes don't suffer from [versioning issues that interfaces face](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/04/10/111042.aspx), which is a bonus.

I can code my application, provide default implementations of the abstract base class, test it and deploy it without actually having to have a different version for each client.  As clients request different storage methods, a different implementation can be supplied and used at runtime via [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373721/example-of-dependency-injection-with-only-base-class).